# how to delay splash fragment time to complete lottie animation

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

This is my splashfragment. I have created the lottie animation which is around 3sec long and it work fine but screen changes before the animation is completed.

```
class SplashFragment : Fragment()  {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?) =
        FragmentSplashBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).root

}
```

Comment: Where's the animation code, please add the full code

Comment: trying to add the code but there is some error while saving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Delay Use Handler**

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            //Do something after 3sc
        }, 3000)
```

Comment: How to use handler in fragments?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after managing to use handler, the startup splash is working as need.

Answer (score 0):

```
lottieAnimationView.addAnimatorListener(object : AnimatorListener{
            override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animator?) {
                Log.d("Lottie","Animation start")
            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animator?) {
                Log.d("Lottie","Animation end")
            }

            override fun onAnimationCancel(p0: Animator?) {
                Log.d("Lottie","Animation Cancelled")
            }

            override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animator?) {
                Log.d("Lottie","Animation repeat")
            }

        })
```

Go to next screen when **onAnimationEnd** triggered.

Comment: How to use this code, i am not much familiar with lottie